# Simple way to create an ERD for a database design review

Tags: database-design, schema, fluent-nhibernate, diagram

I am working on a new application that uses a jet (MS Access) database.  I have built the database using FluentNHibernate's AutoMapping feature from my C# objects.

I need to present this database for an on-line WebEx design review on Tuesday and am looking for a tool to create ERD's for my database that I can group onto slides.

The diagramming in MS Access is poor-to-unusable.

I have: VS2008 Pro, MS Access 2007, Visio 2007, Visio for Enterprise Architects,  etc...
        My C# Code
        Schema exported with NHibernate Hbm2Ddl
        hbm.xml mapping files created by FluentNHibernate
        .accdb file containing the database

I need: quick, free and easy way to create clear diagrams.

Since I have everything for Fluent NH and NHibernate, I could use their drivers/dialects to create a schema for any supported database to use in generating the diagrams.

Any suggestions to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your MS Access DB has all the attributes of a real DB like constraints etc... then Visio should import the DB. If that it not working for you... import the DB into SQL Server. SQL Server has some rudimentary tools for drawing basic ERDs... and Visio with import from SLQ Server.

The "correctness" and "complexity" of the ERD is going to be up to you in the end and how you extend the captured data.

Good luck

Comment: Yes, it is a real database. Visio does not understand the .accdb format.  I can convert it to a mdb - but sql express may be better option.

Comment: I never meant to suggest that it was not a real DB. I believe that Visio can read the DB's schema via odbc.

Comment: I didn't think you were suggesting it wasn't - I was just inferring that it had attributes and constraints.  I ended up using Access for the diagrams as I didn't have time to install SQL Server or learn ODBC.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have Visio 2007, you can "reverse engineer" the DB from either a SQL Server, Access or other driver compatible data source.

1. Create a new database document (aka: Database Model Diagram)
2. From the new "Database" menu select reverse engineer

From that point on, you'll be connecting to your desired data source. The last step asks if you want to add the tables as new shapes. Select "yes" and you'll have a beautiful Visio style ERD. I believe you can also refresh your model after changes.

Comment: +1 - Visio's DB reverse engineering tool is actually very good.  I also recommend this approach.